# React-Native 0.60+ with linked libs not running despite "Dependency Graph" loading

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-code-push

I have an ejected react-native app with multiple linked libraries which fails to run in Android (works in iOS).  The Dependency Graph loads to 100% and it shows the the splash screen on the emulator sometimes, but it immediately crashes when the emulator tries to load the js bundle.

**Relevant packages in package.json**

```
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.6.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.16",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.5",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"
    firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // required by react-native-image-crop-picker
  }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
  entryFile: "index.js",
  enableHermes: false,
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
  lintOptions {
    disable 'GradleCompatible'
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
  }

  // because of firestore:
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.HIDDEN"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    // because of firestore:
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
  splits {
    abi {
      reset()
      enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
      universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
      include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    debug {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
      // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
      // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
      def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
      def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
      if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
        output.versionCodeOverride =
          versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
      }
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

  // RNFirebase required dependencies
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
  // RNFirebase modules
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:17.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'

  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
  implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.HIDDEN;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.geolocation.GeolocationPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.reactnative.ivpusic.imagepicker.PickerPackage;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
// optional packages - add/remove as appropriate
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestorePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.functions.RNFirebaseFunctionsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.instanceid.RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.links.RNFirebaseLinksPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.perf.RNFirebasePerformancePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
        new GeolocationPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
        new LinearGradientPackage(),
        new PickerPackage(),
        new CodePush("HIDDEN", getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG),
        new RNFirebasePackage(),
        // add/remove these packages as appropriate
        new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseFunctionsPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseInstanceIdPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseLinksPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePerformancePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseStoragePackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, false);
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.HIDDEN;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "CashoutSports";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi try to open app android studio and take a look at logcat debug messages. You should be able to see exactly what went wrong as it will provide you with crash message. It will help to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on React-native project. But I think there's something wrong in `MainActivity.java`.

In Android, normally we start initial UI code after  `super.onCreate()`.
Maybe you can call `SplashScreen.show` after call super.onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
SplashScreen.show(this);  // here
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.  Still not working sadly though.